# Adding custom responsive classes in TAILWIND's css

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, tailwind-css

When adding

```
<div class="md:grid-flow-col">
```

nothing happens. This is because md:grid-flow-col isn't included in the tailwind css when I look through the document.

In my styles.css I can see all the classes I can use for tailwind. For example:

```
  .md\:grid-cols-2{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }

  .md\:grid-cols-5{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }

  .md\:flex-row{
    flex-direction: row;
  }
```

I want to add:

```
.md\:grid-flow-col{
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
```

since I can't apply `<div class="md:grid-flow-col">` and change the grid layout the way I want.
Whenever I save the document my changes are removed automatically.

Does anyone know how to add classes that will be applicably when I try to use them in a responsive layout?

Comment: `md:grid-flow-col` should work, here is a demo, https://play.tailwindcss.com/layNsBXpeA, there must be another reason why that class is not showing in your output css.

Answer (score 1):

here you only make the class component, no need for breakpoints / responsive design

[Adding custom style](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-component-classes)

```css
@layer components {
  grid-flow-col {
  @apply grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
}
```